# Proxy of Proxy being created in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

Is DefaultAutoProxyCreator needed if tx:annotation-driven is already enabled ?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator">
        <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

It seems when there are both of them enabled, then proxy of proxies start getting created and starts failing.

Having only tx-annotation enabled, I have disabled spring-aspect and cglib also in maven dependencies. Do I need to have cglib even in Spring 4 for class based proxies like above ?

Spring version : 4.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you don't really need the explicit `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` unless you have specific `Advisors` that you are using for cross cutting purpose - if so I feel that an @AspectJ approach may be cleaner.

Also, disabling cglib explicitly does not have any effect, Spring comes packaged with its own copy of CGLIB.

Comment: I indeed have an Around advice. you are suggesting to use @AspectJ instead , for that do I need to add spring-aspect as well or default interface based proxy will work as enabled by tx annotation ?

Comment: Won't enabling <aop:aspectj-autoproxy /> start clashing again with <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/> ?

Comment: No, it will not, `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` will only create proxies based on beans that have @Aspectj annotations on it, and will not proxy the transaction one's.

Comment: ok got it, so both classes and interfaces having @ Aspectj will be proxied by <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/> , at the same time I can have <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/> for @ Transactional at class and interface levels